# dbt-athena-comunity package with gitActions

Tags: git, amazon-athena, dbt, git-workflow

Unable to properly execute workflow on gitActions using dbt-athena-community package. When executing the following credential issue appears:

**error log from workflow git action execution**

```
dbt.exceptions.DbtProfileError: Runtime Error
Credentials in profile "default", target "dbt_dev" invalid: Runtime Error
Could not find adapter type athena!
```

dbt-athena-community package demands a live connection, but it seems the credentials profile does not work.

Here is my project structure as well as config files.

**Project folder structure**

```
./.github/workflows/lint_models.yml
./models <----.sql files to lint
./.sqlfluff
./profiles.yml
```

**profiles.yml**

```
default:
  outputs:
    dbt_dev:
      database: awsdatacatalog
      region_name: eu-west-2
      s3_staging_dir: s3://athena-query-results-XXX/
      schema: dbt_test
      type: athena
      aws_profile_name: prof_name  <-- as per comment removed this line
      work_group: primary
  target: dbt_dev
```

**.sqlfluff**

```
[sqlfluff]
templater = dbt
dialect = athena
sql_file_exts = .sql

[sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
project_dir = ./
profiles_dir = ./
profile = default  <-- as per comment removed this line
target = dbt_dev   <-- as per comment removed this line
```

**lint_models.yml**

```
name: dbt sqlfluff
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  test-check:

    name: runner / sqlfluff (github-check)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: install python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.11.2
      
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: install dbt adapters
        run: |
          pip install dbt-athena-community==1.4.1
          dbt deps
          dbt --version
      
      - name: sqlfluff
        uses: yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff@v3.6.0
        env:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }} 
        id: lint-sql
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
          reporter: github-pr-review
          sqlfluff_version: "1.4.5"
          sqlfluff_command: "fix" # Or "lint"
          config: "${{ github.workspace }}/.sqlfluff"
          paths: '${{ github.workspace }}/models'
          
      - name: 'Show outputs (Optional)'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results }}' | jq -r '.'
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results-rdjson }}' | jq -r '.'
```

Note, both secrets are the same used to run in local machine through AWS Boto credentials, no issue on local machine.

AWS credentials

When running locally credentials do work, installed AWS cli and configure boto credentials for the profile.

I'm assuming something similar should be done in the workflow that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are passing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in your env therefore you don't need to setup the `aws_profile_name: prof_name` in your profiles. The adapter uses the standard boto3 authentication, and it looks for `prof_name` in your ~/.aws/config or `~/.aws/credentials`, if you don't set any profile the `AWS_*` variables are used.

You might want to use 2 different profiles, one for working locally, with aws_profile_name set, and one for the CI/CD without the aws_profile_name set.

Comment: Hi nicor88, thanks for the quick replay, deleted the property aws_profile_name from profiles.yml, but still same issue. I'm currently clueless, updated the post, but basically as error states Could not find adapter type Athena!. I went and added an step to install it and same issue

Comment: the issue is related to sqlfluff, as you are using 1.4.5 and athena community 1.4.1 that uses dbt >= 1.4.0. Sqlfluff needs to be bumpted to >=2.0.0, try that out and let me know if it fixes the issue. Also consider to use db-athena slack channel in dbt slack workspace :)

Comment: Hi nicor88 post you comment as an answer, I was about to answer my own question, but you gave me hints and discovered the same

Basically created requirements.txt and added sqlfluff==2.0.2
sqlfluff-templater-dbt==2.0.2
dbt-athena-community==1.4.1

once it did it worked !!